# What is the default consistency level in spring-data-cassandra?

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

If I don't set any read/write consistency level at all in my spring-data-cassandra project, what will be my consistency level for reads? What about writes?

*(I asked this question [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/spring-data-cassandra/DbW2sp0jg9k/kiSDv89pjp0J), but the Google Group is now locked)*

Comment: Looks like it's Consistency level ONE. Am I right? http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/1.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Query.html#getConsistencyLevel()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default consistency level used by the driver, if not set, is one. Since spring-data-cassandra, as they claim is:

> Based on the latest DataStax Enterprise CQL Java Driver

the default CL is one.

Answer (score 0):

See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-145 & https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-146.  I am working on this in branch https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/tree/DATACASS-145.  When DATACASS-145 is done, I can move on to DATACASS-146.

I don't think it's going to make it into 1.1.0; 1.1.1 is likely.