# spring-data-cassandra set consistency level

Tags: java, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spring-data-cassandra (1.3.1.RELEASE) to connect to a cassandra database. Is there a way to change the consistency level in spring-data-cassandra.
By default it is level 1 ([What is the default consistency level in spring-data-cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066566/what-is-the-default-consistency-level-in-spring-data-cassandra)). But how to change that?

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, it looks like there is no way to set a custom consistency level yet: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-145

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to set a custom consistency level when using the CrudRepository Interface of spring-data-cassandra. There is an open issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-14. Reason is that the SimpleCassandraRepository which implements the methods of the interface calls the CassandraOperations methods without the WriteOptions parameter.

**My solution**: I wrote a custom crudrepository implementation, in this I can set the consistency level on my own.

Comment: is still this issue or it fixes ?, i also want to set custom consistency level in spring-data-casasandra

Answer (score 6):

You can now set this level in spring boot by setting the following properties in application.properties file.

```
spring.data.cassandra.consistency-level=quorum
spring.data.cassandra.serial-consistency-level=quorum
```

Comment: Do you know which version added this?

Answer (score 4):

Docs say you can set it as annotation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.repositories.queries.options .

IMO, it is always better to control the consistency level per request rather than per application.
Repositories:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

    @Consistency(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE)
    List<Person> findByLastname(String lastname);

    List<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname, QueryOptions options);
}
```

CassandraTemplate:

```
cassandraTemplate.insert(myEntity, new WriteOptions().builder()
                    .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM).build())
```

Answer (score 2):

Resuscitating this old thread in case anyone else stumbles here with the same/similar issue.

For `spring-data-cassandra:3.4.0` using `DataStax` I've made it work using:

```
@Configuration 
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    public CassandraAdminTemplate cassandraTemplate() {
        CassandraAdminTemplate adminTemplate = super.cassandraTemplate();
        CqlTemplate cqlTemplate = (CqlTemplate) adminTemplate.getCqlOperations();
        cqlTemplate.setConsistencyLevel(DefaultConsistencyLevel.valueOf("LOCAL_QUORUM"));
        cqlTemplate.setSerialConsistencyLevel(DefaultConsistencyLevel.valueOf("LOCAL_SERIAL"));
        return adminTemplate;
    } }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

These are the consistency levels defined right now :
 **ANY,   ONE          ,
    TWO         ,
    THREE        ,
    QUORUM       ,
    ALL          ,
    LOCAL_QUORUM,
    EACH_QUORUM ,
    SERIAL       ,
    LOCAL_SERIAL , 
    LOCAL_ONE** .
If you are talking about using other than these, I don't think there is a pluggable solution for that right now , where you define number of nodes that will participate to assert required consistency.
If you want to use any of the above defined consistencies ,
an example would be :

```
        Select s = QueryBuilder.select().from("employee");
        s.where(QueryBuilder.eq("id", "234"));
        s.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM) ;
```

Comment: Thank you - maybe my question was not clear enough. I want to use the defined levels, but also if I make use of the CrudRepository Interface. So when I build a custom repository which extends the CrudRepository Interface and call for example the method save(T) then I will set the consistency level. But it looks like there is no way to do that (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-145). Reason is that the SimpleCassandraRepository which implements the methods of the interface calls the CassandraOperations methods without the WriteOptions parameter.

Comment: Ok. It's better if you could write your solution as an answer and accept it, so that the question may be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean by "If you are **not using boot** and want to set this globally, give this a shot"
I used spring boot and this worked`

```
@Configuration     
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {




@Override
public QueryOptions getQueryOptions() {
    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.TWO);
    return queryOptions;
}

@Override
protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return keyspaceName;
}

@Override
public CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster = super.cluster();
    cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
    cluster.setPort(port);
    cluster.setUsername(username);
    cluster.setPassword(password);
    return cluster;
}
//Also added @Import to Main class

@Import(CassandraConfig.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Vexxxxxxy.class)
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackageClasses = Txxxxxry.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { Entity.class, Vxxxxity.class })
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.xx.xxx")
public class DrixxxxxxxxMain`
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to set it in the application.properties file:
spring.data.cassandra.consistency-level=LOCAL_QUORUM

Answer (score 0):

As of `spring-data-cassandra` **release 1.5**, consistency level is already configurable (see `org.springframework.cassandra.core.QueryOptions#setConsistencyLevel(org.springframework.cassandra.core.ConsistencyLevel))`

It may be specified as a part of `QueryOptions` either for a single query via `org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlOperations#execute(java.lang.String, org.springframework.cassandra.core.QueryOptions)` , or for all types of queries via `org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate#addQueryOptions`

Also it's possible to set consistency level via `WriteOptions` and then pass them to `org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations#insert(T, org.springframework.cassandra.core.WriteOptions)`